# Return Time Series in MVC Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Just beginning in C# coming from a Wolfram Language background. Trying to build a website that displays collected telemetry from weather (and other) sensors. I want to be able to pass data from a SQL Server database that contains `datetime2` and `double` data types to the view in JSON format. Having trouble building a collection including the `DateTime` format.

**Model**
*(DLWeatherMain)*

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WeatherViewer.Models
{
    public partial class DlMainWeather
    {
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime TmStamp { get; set; }
        public double? AirTempAvg { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

*(TelemetryDataContext)*

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace WeatherViewer.Models
    {
        public partial class TelemetryDataContext : DbContext
        {
            public TelemetryDataContext()
            {
            }

            public TelemetryDataContext(DbContextOptions<TelemetryDataContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<DlMainWeather> DlMainWeather { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
                {
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connectionstring");
                }
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.2-servicing-10034");


                modelBuilder.Entity<DlMainWeather>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.TmStamp,})
                        .HasName("PK__DL_MAIN___B3E4C26B9637DE80");

                    entity.ToTable("DL_MAIN_Weather");

                    entity.Property(e => e.AirTempAvg).HasColumnName("AirTemp_Avg");

                });

            }
        }
    }
```

*(WeatherDataAccessLayer)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace WeatherViewer.Models
{
    public class WeatherDataAccessLayer
    {
        TelemetryDataContext db = new TelemetryDataContext();
        public IEnumerable<DlMainWeather> GetTemperatures(double backtime)
        {
            IEnumerable<DlMainWeather> temparray = db.DlMainWeather
                            .Where(dt => dt.TmStamp.Date > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-backtime))
                            .Select(dt => new { dt.TmStamp.Date, dt.AirTempAvg });
            return temparray;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WeatherViewer.Models;

namespace WeatherViewer.Controllers
{

    public class WeatherController : Controller
    {
        WeatherDataAccessLayer weatherobj = new WeatherDataAccessLayer();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult TemperatureSummary()
        {
            return PartialView("_TemperatureReport");
        }

        public JsonResult TemperatureReturn()
        {
            List<DlMainWeather> temparray = new List<DlMainWeather>();
            temparray = weatherobj.GetTemperatures(12).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(temparray);
        }
    }
}
```

So, my problem lies with the DataAccessLayer. As is passing the `temparray` from the DAL is throwing errors in converting to IEnumerable. What's the best way to pass time series (or mixed datatype arrays in general) from Entity Framework to a View as JSON?

Also: `TmStamp` can be converted to unix time if this makes the problem easier.

Comment: The problem is in `.Select(dt => new { dt.TmStamp.Date, dt.AirTempAvg });`, that `new { }` means an anonymous type. You should be using `new DlMainWeather`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did simplify the problem a little, and there are more fields than `AirTempAvg` in the database table. So I'm still confused at how I would just select the fields `TmStamp` and `AirTempAvg`.

Comment: You didn't get what I wanted to say. I meant continue using everything after the `{` in that line, for example, `.Select(dt => new DlMainWeather { tmStamp = dt.TmStamp.Date`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Gotcha. Anything wrong with using IEnumerable as the collection type or should I look elsewhere?